# Tool Options Controls Don't Respond

Tags: gimp

My tool options controls suddenly grayed out when I was using the clone tool for gimp 2.10 on my mac.  The clone tool still works but I can't change any of  the settings, such as the brush size etc.  The tool options won't work for any other tools now either.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of GIMP?

Comment: You may (repeat, may) find a solution quicker by posting over in the Mac & iOS side at https://apple.stackexchange.com as it might involve MacOS. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling GIMP? Regardless, please amplify the data by advising which version of MacOS as well as the GIMP version, by clicking on [edit] and updating your original question.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a random and undiagnosed bug in GIMP on MacOS with tools locking up:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/1924

It goes back several years:

http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12434